# VS Code C# - can't run console app in debug console, but can in integrated terminal

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm using VS Code for learning C# in university and I have a problem.

Installed official C# VS Code extension and .NET SDK. I can run a simple console application in integrated terminal and input data via Console.ReadLine() but I can't do the same thing during debugging (F5). In debug console I have only this thing without prompt which I did in code:

> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
>   Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and test your applications.
>   Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Loaded 'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\c#_zajecia\helloworld\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\helloworld.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.5\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.5\System.Console.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDPnQ.png)